# Ctrl-C in bash shell kills my postgres server

Tags: bash, background-process

I'm running a postgres server with `pg_ctl start`. The postgres server is running happily in the background; however, if I hit `Ctrl-C` when there is no process running in the foreground, the postgres server is killed. I don't know why it is affected by this signal because I would expect only the foreground shell to receive it. Adding in a trap for `SIGINT` did not seem to help (tried both `trap "" INT` and `trap "" SIGINT`). What can I do?

Comment: Not enough info, but I'd try `trap '' INT #ignore INT`. (Ignore masks get inherited by children. Signal handlers do not).

Comment: Read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1028976/why-ctrlc-in-console-kills-the-background-process) answer to find the reason why Ctrl-C sends SIGINT to your background process.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to add the piece of code where you tried to trap the signal.

Comment: Edited. However, I'm not running a subshell. I'm just using `pg_ctl start`.